# PHP GD, imagepolygon(), How to make the lines smoother?

Tags: php, gd

Im drawing some polygons with PHP GD imagepolygon(). The problem is that i got alot of visible pizels, is there a way to make them smoother?

```
The included image shows the problem, on all the edges i have quite heavy pixelating.
```

[image]

[EDIT]

```
I have tried to use imageantialias() but i dont get it as good as im aiming for. 
I think that i will have to take a look at vector graphics, anyway, here is the image with anti-aliasing if anyone is interested
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your GD image resource is a true color one and you are not using the alpha component (transparency), you can call [imageantialias()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageantialias.php) to enable anti-aliasing.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question even though i will do it with vector graphics since the result wasnt as good as i needed it to be.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to avoid pixellation on line drawings is to use vector graphics rather than pixel-based graphics.

I accept that this would mean a complete rewrite for you, but it will solve the problem completely (and give you more flexibility in the long term).

If you decide to go down this route, my suggestion would be to investigate a Javascript library like [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/). From your PHP code, you would output co-ordinate data rather than the actual graphic, and then load those co-ords into your Javascript code using Ajax and use Raphael to draw the image.

I know that's not a direct answer to your question but I hope it gives you food for thought. (I've given +1 to the antialiasing answer, as it is a direct and good answer for you).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I dont seem to find a polygon option in RaphaelJs?

Comment: In Raphael, use [`path`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path) to create a polygon. This creates a line from a set of points. Use the `Z` option at the end of the points string to define it as a closed polygon. `path` returns a path object, which you can then modify by setting attributes like `fill`, etc.